Insecure CSP value in chrome extension manifest during firebase auth popup signin
I am following this workflow from google to setup signing in users from a Chrome extension. I have added the suggested URLs to the content_security_policy allowlist in my manifest.json V3:
"content_security_policy": { "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com https://securetoken.googleapis.com; object-src 'self';" }
But when I try to load as an extension I get the error  'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com" in directive 'script-src'. Could not load manifest.
I have tried changing manifest version to no avail
FIx:
Use the sandboxed iframe.

Use the sandboxed iframe.

@woxxom thank you so much brother, I saw some of your comments from like 3 years ago man looool, I was losing it.

@woxxom is there also no way to protect your API keys
